# requirejs call outside function with same dependancy

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, esri

How do I call a function with the same dependancy from outside the function? The dependancy is not global it seems so the called function does not know about FeatureLayer

```
require(
[
"esri/map",
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
"esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",
"esri/geometry/Point",
"esri/graphic",
"dojo/domReady!"
], 
function(Map, FeatureLayer, PopupTemplate, Point, Graphic){
   map = new Map("mapDiv", { basemap: "streets", center: [22, 65], zoom: 5 });
   getBasestationList();
};
});

function getBasestationList() {
    fromdatetime = fromdatetime.toLocaleString();
    todatetime = todatetime.toLocaleString();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "post", 
        url: "{% url 'get_latest_basestation_list' %}",
        data: 
        {
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
            "fromdate": fromdatetime,
            "todate": todatetime,
        },
        success: function (data, status) 
        { 
            featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(data, { id: 'basestations' });
            map.addLayers([featureLayer]);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) 
        {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
     }); 
 };
```

However this gives me an error that FeatureLayer is not defined, since it does not have that dependency. How would I add a dependency to an external function and call it from my function?

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass FeatureLayer object to the method like getBasestationList(FeatureLayer) and then see if you can reference it?

Another way to do is it declare a global variable and assign FeatureLayer reference to it.

Issue with your code is that function getBasestationList() appears to be outside the scope. So you need to have a global variable defined to use that object.

Answer (score 0):

put your function getBasestationList() in require function, like code example

```
require(
[
"esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",
"esri/geometry/Point", "esri/graphic", "dojo/domReady!"
], 
function(Map, FeatureLayer, PopupTemplate, Point, Graphic){
  function getBasestationList() {
    fromdatetime = fromdatetime.toLocaleString();
    todatetime = todatetime.toLocaleString();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "post", 
        url: "{% url 'get_latest_basestation_list' %}"
    }); 
  };
  map = new Map("mapDiv", { basemap: "streets", center: [22, 65], zoom: 5 });
  getBasestationList();
});
```